# Wordpress keeps redirecting to root site after saving any setting

Tags: redirect, options

we have the next issue:

We are working in our DEV environment: **[www.oursite.com/blog](http://www.oursite.com/blog)**

But everytime we press the "save settings" button, for example, saving changes inside settings/general it redirects us to the root: **[www.oursite.com](http://www.oursite.com)**

The rest of the links work perfectly, it just happens when we save settings.

We have noticed the input button has a wrong url:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/options-reading.php">
```

We checked other projects with subfolders and it should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/blog/wp-admin/options-reading.php">
```

We already tried disabling al plugins and activating a default wordpress theme but the issue persists.

Thanks.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your WP settings the `site_url()` or `home_url()` are not correct.  You'll want to look for these lines in your `wp_options` db:  `siteurl` and `homeurl`, make sure they're correct.